# Unexpected searching results when using range query with hibernate search

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm currently working on a project to search objects with a time range using hibernate search 4.5.0.final

When I used range query to search results based on timestamps parsed as long value, the search results seems to behave unexpected.

The query I'm using is as followed:

```
BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> b = qb.bool();
    b.should(qb.bool()
        .must(qb.range()
            .onField("windowFrom")
            .below(sv.getFrom().getTimestamp())
            .createQuery())
        .must(qb.range()
            .onField("windowTo")
            .above(sv.getTo().getTimestamp())
            .createQuery())
        .createQuery());
```

Then I tried with some kind of workaround like this:

```
BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> b = qb.bool();
    b.should(qb.bool()
        .must(qb.range()
            .onField("windowFrom")
            .from(Long.parseLong("0"))
            .to(sv.getFrom().getTimestamp())
            .createQuery())
        .must(qb.range()
            .onField("windowTo")
            .from(sv.getTo().getTimestamp())
            .to(Long.parseLong("1450704000000"))
            .createQuery())
        .createQuery());
```

The search works just as I expected.

I'm wondering if I constructed the query in a wrong way. Have anyone else encountered this kind of problems before?

The workaround should works fine but it's not so pretty. So I'm still looking for a solution. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Is sv.getFrom().getTimestamp() returning a long? What happens if you add an explicit cast to long?

Comment: Hi @Hardy. Yes, `sv.getFrom().getTimestamp()` returns a long value. I just tried with casting explicitly to long, the result is the same as before.

Comment: it looks like you inverted below/above ?

Comment: @Sanne I think the logic is right. Nevertheless, I had tried to invert below/above, it still didn't work.